# Laravel website very slow on live server

Tags: php, laravel

I've built [this](http://www.wesocular.com) website with laravel, on my local host it's loading fast. But on a live server it's very slow. I'm not sure if the problem is with my website or the server it's hosted on. 
Can I get suggestions on how to improve website speed please..

Comment: You should check https://gtmetrix.com for suggestion. It give you more info about your website

Comment: Hi Jack
Thank you I'll check it out

Comment: For most recommendations I got good grades (As) , for minify css, & html, javascript  I got an F...so looks like I need to minify my files.

but I'm confused coz I've hosted another laravel website on a different server, with out minifying my files and it loads super fast...
I wanna blame my web host..

Comment: Mya be your old website has less numbers of js and css and this. Try to compare run both site on gtmetrix an you will know the results